# Taking data from related table and populating feature attribute table in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, feature-service, relates, arcgis-collector

Our forester wants trees symbolized red if they haven't been trimmed, green if they've been trimmed.  Trimming info is maintained in the Tree_Maint table, which is a one to many related table to our Trees feature class in an enterprise gdb.  You cannot symbolize a feature from a related table using ArcMap.  I would like to take records from the Tree_Maint table's "Activity" field with the value "Trimmed" for the current year using the "Activity_Date" field and populate the Trimmed records into the Trees attribute table field called "TRIM_STATUS".  This would then allow me to symbolize the trees.

The end result of this work done in ArcMap 10.4.1 will be a feature service that our forester will use via Collector to select a tree and edit the related maintenance table, which I intend to use to update the "TRIM_STATUS".

I'm assuming this might require python, of which I am a novice.

Comment: One to many? Join it back the other way and you should be able to calc... but more about the tree_maint table, does it have multiple entries for each tree related by a unique id? When does a 'trimmed' status get old? (no longer trimmed) and can you tell from just the tree_maint table and todays' date?

Comment: Summarise related table using activity as case field and key statistics, first. Join result with parent.

Comment: Yes, each tree can have multiple maintenance records dating back many years beyond just trimming.  Records are related back to the tree by a unique tree ID.  Trimming occurs annually.  The forester would like to reference Collector to see which trees have been trimmed for the year.  Trees can have trimming records going back many years.

Comment: The end result to what I'm asking is to figure out a way to symbolize a feature by data in a related table so that when the forester edits the tree maint table in the field using collector (to enter that a tree has been trimmed), it changes the symbol of the tree.

Answer (score -2):

This article helps guide you to the answer as well:
https://community.esri.com/message/772784-re-collector-use-related-layer-to-symbolise-feature?commentID=772784#comment-772784
If you look at the section where JerryC and myself chat, we talk about adding the parent fc as many times as you need to place an individual definition query in the parent fc.
The definition query would search all the unique ID's in the parent fc, then search the related records for the unique ID that matches the parent ID, based on another delimiter, such as latest datetime field, and finally another delimiter such as the trimstatus.
You can then symbolize the resulting fc according to the query you input.
The following url describes my understanding of this as of now:
https://community.esri.com/thread/215046-symbolizing-feature-class-using-related-table-values